# App crashes when calling HKHealthStore's execute method on HKStatisticsCollectionQuery

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to retrieve the steps data from Health Kit and get an update everytime this data changes.

But when the `HKHealthStore` calls its execute method on the query, the app crash:

[image]

And I have no idea why. Any help is welcome.

Here is my code:

```
func sretrieveRealTimeSteps(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    var interval = DateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .weekday], from: Date())
    anchorComponents.hour = 0

    guard let anchorDate = calendar.date(from: anchorComponents) else { completion(0); return }
    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else { completion(0); return }

    let realTimeQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                                                    quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                                    options: .cumulativeSum,
                                                    anchorDate: anchorDate,
                                                    intervalComponents: interval)

    realTimeQuery.statisticsUpdateHandler = { query, statistics, results, error in
        guard let statsCollection = results else {
            completion(0)
            return
        }

        statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: Date(), to: Date()) { statistics, stop in
            if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                let value = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                completion(Int(value)) 
            } else {
                completion(0) 
            }
        }
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(realTimeQuery)
}
```

Also, when I used a **one time** query there is no problem:

```
query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
    guard let statsCollection = results else {
        NotificationView.showHealthKitRetrieveInfoFailedNotification()
        completion(nil, error)
        return
    }

    var values = [Int]()

    let endDate = Date()
    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -6, to: endDate) ?? Date()

    statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate) { statistics, stop in
        if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
            let date = statistics.startDate
            let value = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

            values.append(Int(value))

            if date.isSameDayThan(endDate, timeZone: TimeZone.current) { 
                completion(values, nil) 
            }
        } else {
            values.append(0)

            if values.count == 7 {
                stop.pointee = true
                completion(values, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Stacktrace

[image]

Comment: Is there no information on the console about the crash? Did you set up an **exception breakpoint**? Perhaps you defined `healthkitStore` as an implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`), and it is `nil` at the moment you call `healthKitStore.execute(realTimeQuery)`?

Comment: No, this is how I defined healthKitStore: `let healthKitStore: HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()`. And the only information I ever get on the console is `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

Comment: `NSException` sounds like on Objective-C exception. Set up an "exception breakpoint": the debugger will stop at the line where it occurs and meaningful information will be output to the console.

Comment: Whether I enable or disable the NSException breakpoint, I end up at the same first screen I shot. I added the stacktrace.

Comment: Just to be sure, with `initialResultsHandler` I don't need a special key (other than the one needed to read Health Kit data) or capability (like background one) right?

Comment: Not sure about that. You **did** get user authorization to access health data, right?

Comment: Yes I did. It's literally just with `statisticsUpdateHandler` I have a problem. With `initialResultsHandler` it works fine.

Comment: This may be a little late to the party... but perhaps you need to store a reference to the query? Is it trying to call the updateHandler on something that's become `nil`? You should probably be storing it anyway, so that you can call stopUpdates() on it as well.